# DotNet Core 3.1 Authentication: The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, oauth, openid-connect

I keep getting The oauth state was missing or invalid in my Staging server but this code works just fine in my local hosted IIS.

P.s. Before I get sent to a duplicate page, I have tried all the pages in StackOverflow and I have looked all over google. I removed the CallbackPath and that broke as well:

I am using AWS Load balancer with two instances of the app running in IIS 7.

Error: ArgumentException: The 'CallbackPath' option must be provided. (Parameter 'CallbackPath')

DotNet Code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        })
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "SportsEngine";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOAuth("SportsEngine", options =>
        {
            // Client Info
            options.ClientId = Configuration["SSO:SeApiClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["SSO:SeApiClientSecret"];
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth/authorize");

            // Client Endpoints
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["SSO:SSOAuthority"];
            options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["SSO:SSOTokenEndpoint"];

            // Save token
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            // TODO: Need to figure out how to add SeriLog in here
        });

        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddScoped<IContextFactory, DbContextFactory>();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //logger.LogInformation("In Development.");
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();              
        }
        else
        {
            //logger.LogInformation("Not Development.");
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            var forwardingOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            };
            forwardingOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear(); // Loopback by default, this should be temporary
            forwardingOptions.KnownProxies.Clear(); // Update to include

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardingOptions);

            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        // Auth
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        // add caching to pipe
        app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
        {
            // Customize the message template
            options.MessageTemplate = "Handled {RequestPath}";

            // Emit debug-level events instead of the defaults
            options.GetLevel = (httpContext, elapsed, ex) => LogEventLevel.Debug;

            // Attach additional properties to the request completion event
            options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
            {
                diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
                diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
            };
        });
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
    2021-09-08 21:19:21.154 +00:00 [WRN] No XML encryptor configured. Key {c83f05de-c4ba-4fc0-b4d6-f550329e41ef} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-09-08 21:19:21.695 +00:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-09-08 21:19:21.695 +00:00 [INF] Hosting environment: testdrive
2021-09-08 21:19:21.696 +00:00 [INF] Content root path: C:\Octopus\Applications\Testdrive\Machine.MVC\0.0.1995
2021-09-08 21:19:21.786 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://stagingmachine.xyz/oauth/authorize?code=b758c76d24011e86e4c68d9cec728072&state=CfDJ8KjLM7huDtpBl3WGRqwXMZXawockkQzpDjTluDmfzmzN2R2GNrBg7fj0LbsIZavTGXsBscbDxLfjRtXf_8WPCIVUm-FtBiq0lx8jC09ZiXPS_uciWJ0GLcL73Xj3S0kXU8-bgekYUkOfN9UykxIIYLQe9tUeX2RpDWn4Aj5R0BoEJJt-h3jmYaaQwzFAtnQJHbmVWmfA64x01igEan_F6rE  
2021-09-08 21:19:22.072 +00:00 [INF] Error from RemoteAuthentication: The oauth state was missing or invalid..
2021-09-08 21:19:22.082 +00:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2021-09-08 21:19:22.188 +00:00 [INF] No cached response available for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.191 +00:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'Machine.MVC.Controllers.HomeController.Error (Machine.MVC)'
2021-09-08 21:19:22.253 +00:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "Error", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Error() on controller Machine.MVC.Controllers.HomeController (Machine.MVC).
2021-09-08 21:19:22.355 +00:00 [INF] Executing ViewResult, running view Error.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.532 +00:00 [INF] Executed ViewResult - view Error executed in 207.3459ms.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.536 +00:00 [INF] Executed action Machine.MVC.Controllers.HomeController.Error (Machine.MVC) in 279.6243ms
2021-09-08 21:19:22.536 +00:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'Machine.MVC.Controllers.HomeController.Error (Machine.MVC)'
2021-09-08 21:19:22.538 +00:00 [INF] The response could not be cached for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.569 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 796.8368ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
2021-09-08 21:19:22.737 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://stagingmachine.xyz/oauth/img/footer/twitter.png  
2021-09-08 21:19:22.737 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://Stagingmachine.xyz/oauth/img/footer/facebook.png  
2021-09-08 21:19:22.742 +00:00 [INF] No cached response available for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.742 +00:00 [INF] No cached response available for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.746 +00:00 [INF] The response could not be cached for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.746 +00:00 [INF] The response could not be cached for this request.
2021-09-08 21:19:22.750 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 13.9281ms 404 
2021-09-08 21:19:22.750 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 13.3817ms 404
```

Comment: are you using load-balancing? and have multiple copies of the services?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I'm load balancing with AWS and we deploy to multiple instances of IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use load balancing, you need to make sure the client instance that makes the initial authentication request is the same as the one handling the callback with the authorization code. The client needs to remember the state parameter between the calls.

Comment: How do I do that in dotnet core?

Comment: I guess you need to handle this in the load balancer, the request to /signin-oidc sent by the browser needs to go to the same instance that made the initial authentication request. Alternatively, you could try to have a unique redirect_url per client that is hardcoded to each instance. But that all depends on your setup

Comment: Add enabled sticky sessions and got OAuth to work.